# How to boot using splash / quiet after a Minimal installation with no selected packages

Tags: boot, grub2, 17.10, ubuntu-minimal

After installing Ubuntu 17.10 using the [minimial ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and following [this guide](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2361552), I am presented with a blank screen on boot.

There are several filed bugs related to this issue:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/695658
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/761830
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/700686

As I understand it, the reason for this bug is that GRUB selects an incorrect tty on boot, as it expects an X11 server to be available.

Since installing zero packages is technically not supported by the installer, I can see why this problem has been given low priority. It's also easy to switch to the correct tty by pressing Alt+F1, which, assuming you have an encrypted volume, will present you with an Ubuntu branded screen to enter your decryption passphrase.

If I install a display manager, e.g. GNOME with `apt install gdm3`, the behaviour persists, although (and I think this information may be relevant) I now have to switch between tty2 and tty1 a couple of times, ending on tty1, before I see anything, e.g. `Alt+F2` then `Alt+F1`, repeated twice. This may be a new bug, since my reading of the currently filed bugs seems to indicate that installing a display manager should eliminate the problem.

The guide I followed proposes a fix that involves editing `/etc/default/grub` as follows:

Old: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

New: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`

This completely disables the splash screen and gives full scrolling-text feedback while booting until it finally presents a text mode prompt for the decryption password.

Something else that may be relevant:

In `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` there is this code:

```
vt_handoff="1"

#snip

if [ "$vt_handoff" = 1 ]; then
  for word in $GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT; do
    if [ "$word" = splash ]; then
      GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT \$vt_handoff"
    fi
  done
fi
```

**What I would like**: a minimal install with quiet boot and the attractive full-screen LVM decryption dialog (crucially, in my opinion, with on screen feedback when you type).

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried following the 'first boot' and 'get a working distro' sections of the guide you linked? You probably have, but it would be helpful to know for sure.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to select just one package in the installer... Try installing Plymouth and see if that gets you what you need. Hopefully it's minimal enough for you!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. If I follow the get a working distro section I get the 'server style' bootup with console output, which is fine (although it would be nice to have that hidden) but the annoying thing for me is the LVM decryption prompt which is console style, with no feedback when you type. It's just that little bit less user friendly than the Ubuntu default where you get placeholder *s and the field is front and centre.

Comment: I know these quibbles are pretty minor, I'm just curious to know what the reason is. What I want seems so close with just having to switch tty!

The minimal installer provides a list of meta-packages, not sure if Plymouth is in there but it does seem to be exactly what I am after. I will try that and report back. Otherwise, perhaps the answer is to select ubuntu-desktop and then diff the grub configuration between that and not selecting anything.

Comment: Ok thanks, I hope Plymouth works for you. Don't forget to report back, though, I'd like to hear how it goes, thanks!

Comment: I actually just checked and it seems that the Plymouth package is installed on my system. It's not a dependency of gdm3, maybe it is part of the base ubuntu installation?

I don't have a spare machine to test on unfortunately so I will have to wait to see if it is visible in the list of options provided in the minimal installer - will report back when I get a chance though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm still not entirely sure this will work for you, I'm going to try answering your question anyway. If Plymouth is already installed, then I recommend installing plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo:

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

Once that is installed, or if it is installed already, you should run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

I'm not entirely sure about what options it may give you there, but if it asks, you want the Ubuntu logo theme. After that, you'll be nearly finished. Although this step may or may not be required in more recent versions of Ubuntu, I still recommend that you run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

One more thing: You'll need to set your grub configuration back to what it was before, so you should edit `/etc/default/grub` again, and put the `"quiet splash"` part back.

That should fix your issues with the decryption dialog, and show you the pretty Ubuntu logo screen on boot! I hope this solves it for you, or that you've found another solution. Thanks very much!

Comment: It worked! I think that all I needed was the plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo package. The configuration gave me three options, and the Ubuntu logo theme was already selected. It also appears that the installation script for the theme package executes the final command so as you suspected that was not necessary.

Comment: Hooray! I'm glad that worked for you. Also, yes, the update-initramfs isn't really necessary since 16.04 (or maybe earlier), but it's not a bad idea to run it anyway, just in case there's something else that needs to be updated with your specific system.